# How do I animate dynamic text with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, animate.css

A span element,

```
<span id="example">Start</span>
```

JavaScript

```
var texts = ["example1", "example2", "example3"];
var count = 0;
function changeText() {
    $("#example").text(texts[count]);
    count < 3 ? count++ : count = 0;
}
setInterval(changeText, 500);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/989dbjn8/)

How can I add animations to the newly added element to span,

I want use animations from [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/), `bounceIn` while the element enters and `bounceOut` while the item disappears and so on till the last item in the list.

Update:

Fiddle updated with animate.css

Answer (score 2):

Try utilizing [jQuery UI - Bounce Effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/bounce-effect/)

css

```
#example {
    top:50px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
```

js

```
var texts = ["example1", "example2", "example3"];
var count = 0;

function changeText() {
    $("#example").delay(10)
        .hide("bounce", {
        times: 3
    }, 1500, function () {
        $(this).text(texts[count]).show("bounce", {
            times: 3
        }, 1500, function () {
            count < 2 ? count++ : count = 0;
            changeText();
        });
    });
}
changeText();
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/989dbjn8/3/

Comment: would like to use `animate.css`. jQuery UI is another package, can't include just to animate a single part!

Comment: @Marty _"would like to use animate.css"_ See Question title _"How do I animate dynamic text with JavaScript?"_ ? fwiw, animate.css is 3272 lines https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/animate.css . If visit http://jqueryui.com/download , at "Components" select "toggle all" , then scroll down and select only "Effects Core" and "Bounce Effect" , the resulting file should be 1419 lines uncompressed http://jsfiddle.net/0uLfckq2/. Could browse source of either, isolate the "bounce" effect , use only those portions ? See also http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js

Answer (score 1):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYJsK/266/) should work.

```
var texts = ["example1", "example2", "example3"];
var count = 0;
function changeText() {
    $('#example').addClass('animated infinite bounce');
    $("#example").text(texts[count]);
    count < 3 ? count++ : count = 0;
}
setInterval(changeText, 500);
```

Comment: i mean the effect works when the item is loaded, while not when the item is disappeared.

Comment: You did not load `animate.css`... look at External Resources options: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.6/animate.min.css
Nor did you have the line that adds the CSS class to the span. `$('#example').addClass('animated infinite bounce');`

Comment: see the css box on the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/989dbjn8/) . Sorry your answer couldn't be added to fiddle because, its just adding the `infinite` class that just result in looping the animations forever from the first, that's why your answer doesn't `bounceOut`

Comment: half of what I want, I need the current element to `bounceOut` just before the next element `bounceIn`

Comment: I really don't know, since this is a CSS effect I don't know how to catch its end with jQuery, you could achieve the same thing if you use only jQuery, is that something you're willing to try?

Comment: all you need is to add the class `bounceIn` to get the text bounce in and remove the class `bounceIn` and add the class `bounceOut` to the text bounce out.

Comment: He needs a delay though, like... you have to actually use a timer to see how many seconds each effect takes place and then calculate exactly when you want to fire the `bounceOut` event, so when it's over the new word will appear.